# No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.repo.UserRepository' available

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

This is my first try for Spring Data JPA with Spring MVC and I am not able to solve this error.

**Error Log**

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.repo.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4725)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.repo.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
>       ... 24 more

**UserRepository.java**

```
 @Repository
 public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

 }
```

**MainController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
        System.out.println("------>>>>>>>>>>" + user.getName());
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<User>> listAllUsers() {
        List<User> users = (List<User>)userRepository.findAll();
        if (users.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("List is empty oops..!!");
            return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        }
        System.out.println("Got the List...!!");
        System.out.println("Name of First User---->>>>" + users.get(0).getName());
        return new ResponseEntity<List<User>>(users, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

**AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();  
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF");  
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;  
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/spring_database");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(){
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        factory.setPackagesToScan(User.class.getPackage().getName());
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factory.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factory.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

**User.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    /*Getters and Setters*/
```

And this is my project structure

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TIaw.png)

What am i missing here? or What is my mistake over here? Can anyone solve this?

Comment: You need to tell us the package of each of those classes.

Comment: `@ComponentScan("com.exampl")` a E is missing

Comment: @JBNizet I have attached the image for my project structure

Comment: @RC. added that still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell spring where to look for repositories:

`@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)`

Comment: I have the same problem as Dishank. Tried this but does not change anything.